# Argument 1 passed to ::__construct() must be an instance of DateTimeInterface

Tags: php, symfony, service, calendar, sonata-admin

I am building a calendar into sonata admin. I am doing it as a block service.
So I wrote a CalendarBlockService.php

```html
<?php

namespace CD\CarsBundle\Block\Service;

use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager; // mis car je vais devoir récupérer les immatriculations disponibles par jour => donc requête bdd dans repository => utilisation de l'entitymanager




class CalendrierBlockService extends BaseBlockService
{
 // mettre le code des méthodes nécessaires pour le calendrier (block service) avec les données à retrouver dedans

 /**
  * @var Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext
  */
 protected $securityContext; 

 /**
  * @var EntityManager
  */
 protected $em;

 /**
  * @var \CD\CarsBundle\Service\Calendrier\Calendrier
  */
 private $calendrier;

 /**
  * @var \CD\CarsBundle\Service\Calendrier\Jour
  */
 private $jour;




  // CalendrierBlockService Constructor

 /**
  * @param string $name
  * @param EngineInterface $templating
  * @param Pool $pool
  * @param EntityManager $em
  * @param SecurityContext $securityContext
  * @param Calendrier $calendrier
  * @param Jour $jour
  */
 public function __construct(
  $name,
  EngineInterface $templating,
  Pool $pool,
  EntityManager $em,
  SecurityContext $securityContext,
  Calendrier $calendrier,
  Jour $jour)
 {
  parent::__construct($name, $templating);

  $this->pool            = $pool;
  $this->em              = $em;
  $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
  $this->calendrier      = $calendrier;
  $this->jour            = $jour;
 }
 
  // Name

 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
 public function getName()
 {
  return 'Disponibilités';
 }

  // Default settings (valid options for a block of this type)

 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
 public function setDefaultSettings(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
 {
  $resolver->setDefaults(array(
   'title'    => 'Calendrier des disponibilités',
   'template' => 'CDCarsBundle:Block:calendrier.html.twig',
  ));
 }

 /**
  * @return array
  */
 public function getDefaultSettings()
 {
  return array();
 }

        // Implement the execute method which must return a response object, which is used to render the block
  // The block context knows the defaults settings, but they can be overwritten in the call to render the block

 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
 public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
 {
  // Pick up the instance of the vehicles repository
  $repovehicules = $this->em->getRepository('CDCarsBundle:Vehicules');

  // Get the available plates numbers (an array) which will be render to a template
  $immatriculations = $repovehicules->getAvailables();

  // Pick up the calendar ( !!! be careful about the config and the construct if the calendar is declared as a service)
  $calendar = new CD\CarsBundle\Resources\views\Block();   //>>>>> right or not?

  // Setup the variables entered into the method "render Response" (the 3 first are required)
  $variable = array(
   'block'            => $blockContext->getBlock(),
   'base_template'    => $this->pool->getTemplate('CDCarsBundle:Block:calendrier.html.twig'),
   'seetings'         => $blockContext->getSettings(),
   'immatriculations' => $immatriculations,
   'calendrier'       => $calendar
   );

  // Now execute the template and send a response
  return $this->renderResponse($blockContext->getTemplate(), $variable, $response);
 }

  // To edit in sonata admin

 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
 public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block)
 {
 }

  // To validate in sonata admin

 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
 public function validateBlock(ErrorElement $errorElement, BlockInterface $block)
 {
 }

  
}
```

And Calendrier.php (which is not finished)

```html
<?php

namespace  CD\CarsBundle\Service\Calendrier;

class Calendrier
{
 // With this file, I collect all the informations of each days of each month of the year

 // Pick up the days of a month (array with days which are numbered)

 /**
  * @param string | interger $month
  * @return CD\CarsBundle\Service\Calendrier\Jour
  */
 public function getDays($month)
 {
  return $this->days[$month];
 }

}
```

And Jour.php

```html
<?php

namespace CD\CarsBundle\Service\Calendrier;

class Jour
{
 // With this file, I collect all the informations about one day (example: 21-09-2016)

 // Days are defined with constants values (reusable everywhere in the app)

 const WEEK_MONDAY    = "1";
 const WEEK_TUESDAY   = "2";
 const WEEK_WEDNESDAY = "3";
 const WEEK_THURSDAY  = "4";
 const WEEK_FRIDAY    = "5";
 const WEEK_SATURDAY  = "6";
 const WEEK_SUNDAY    = "7";

 /**
  * Then the date is build (format year-month-day) with a constructor
  * @param \DateTimeInterface $day
  */
 public function __construct(\DateTimeInterface $day)
 {
  $this->year    = $day->format('Y');
  $this->month   = $day->format('m');
  $this->day     = $day->format('Y-m-d');
  $this->dayWeek = $day->getDayWeek($day);
 }

 /**
  * Transform date from DateTime format to String format
  *
  * @return string
  */
 public function __toString()
 {
  return $this->getDateString();
 }

 /**
  * Pick up the date in string
  * @return string
  */
 public function getDateString()
 {
  return $this->year .''. $this->month .''. $this->day;
 }

 /**
  * Pick up the year
  * @return string
  */
 public function getYear()
 {
  return $this->year;
 }

 /**
  * Pick up the month
  * @return string
  */
 public function getMonth()
 {
  return $this->month;
 }

 /**
  * Pick up the day
  * @return string
  */
 public function getDay()
 {
  return $this->day;
 }

 /**
  * Pick up the day week (number of the day -> example: monday = 1)
  * @return string
  */
 public function getDayWeek()
 {
  return $this->dayWeek;
 }

 /**
  * Saturdays and Sundays are days off (days without bookings, so no need to have the list of available vehicles for those 2 days) -> DayWithout
  * @return boolean
  */
 public function getDayWithout()
 {
  return $this->dayWithout;
 }

 // Only the current class will have access to the field or method.

 private $day;
 private $month;
 private $year;
 private $dayWeek;
 private $dayWithout;
}
```

I declared as service into my bundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```html
sonata.block.service.calendrier:
        class: CD\CarsBundle\Block\Service\CalendrierBlockService
        arguments:
            - "sonata.block.service.calendrier"
            - '@templating'
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
            - '@security.context'
            - '@cd_cars.calendrier'
            - '@cd_cars.jour'
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.block }

    cd_cars.calendrier:
        class: CD\CarsBundle\Service\Calendrier\Calendrier

    cd_cars.jour:
        class: CD\CarsBundle\Service\Calendrier\Jour
```

When I refresh the page , I have the following error message :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to CD\CarsBundle\Service\Calendrier\Jour::__construct() must be an instance of DateTimeInterface, none given, called in E:\www\flotte\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 815 and defined") in SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig at line 42.

So, I understand that the argument 1 is missing and that it should be an instance of DateTime Interface. However, I can't find how I can write it.

Anyone to help me , please.

Comment: Hi Coralie, at begining I used to code in French too (comments and classes names). I can just encourage you to code in English, just in case where your program should be debug by someone else. Imagine you've to debug something commented in Polish... Very hard (It was my case...)... [just a comment]

Comment: I understand perfectly don't worry. For my personal projects, I code in English. However, this internship project must be coded in french (asked by the client). So I have to respect that.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your architecture - services are supposed to be objects that will be initialized (constructed) only once and then reused in every other use-case. So you cannot initialize your Jour class with a datetime parameter, because then your class will not be reusable. Jour does not seem to be a service.

You can

- set DateTime to Jour class each time you use it
- or provide DateTime to Jour methods when needed
- or (and I recommend this solution) dont make your Jour class a service and initialize it yourself in CalendrierBlockService::_construct (or anywhere else you find optimal)